# Gatsby conditional rendering of a component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a template like this:

```
const Template = ({ data }) => {
  const { id } = data.Page
  const postNode = data.Page

  return (
    <Layout>
       // conditional logic here
       // if {id} is 40 output <AdditionalContent />
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

I want to know if it is possible to check the `id` to see if it is 40, then output `<AdditionalContent>` component.

Answer (score 6):

You can define like this

```
const Template = ({ data }) => {
  const { id } = data.Page
  const postNode = data.Page

  return (
    <Layout>
      {id===40 && <AdditionalContent />}
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: this worked :) what does `&&` mean in here? is there another way to do conditional renderings as well?

Comment: @RainMan it is similar to if condition only not if else condition... so if id matches then only render that component.

Comment: @RainMan if answer is helpful for you please accept it